# Function Doesn't Work: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELETE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a function inside Postgres. For some reason my query works perfectly fine when I run it from inside the Query tool. Once I added the query to my function, I get the error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELETE"

Not sure what is the problem.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.remove_email_header()
    RETURNS pg_trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
DELETE FROM public.spam_dictionary WHERE words LIKE '%FROM%';
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.remove_email_header()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two Things to note.

A plpgsql Postgres function uses `BEGIN END`

The plpgsql should not be quoted.

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_email_header()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
DELETE FROM public.spam_dictionary WHERE words LIKE '%FROM%';
END 
$BODY$;
```